# If Statement doesn't even seem to exist

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement

Im trying to write a program that takes array inputs from the user and assigns the the odd elements to the first index until there are no more odd elements and the even elements are assigned to the end of the array until they're done so for example

Assuming this a size 10 array,The user enteres 1 for the first element and 2 for the second element and 3 for the third element ,so the final array would have indices 0 and 1 to have the values of 1 and 3 and indice 10 to have the value of 2 and so on and so forth,and here's my code

```
int main() {

  int array1[31];
  int array2[31];

  for(int i=0;i<31;i++) {
    if(scanf("%d",&array1[i])%2==0) {
      array2[31-i]=array1[i];
    }
    else {
      array2[i]=array1[i]
    }
  }

  for (int i=0;i<31;i++) {
    printf ("%d\t",array2[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But this code is only printing exactly what the user has entered in the exact same order,it's like my if condition doesn't execute and im not sure why,I'm still a beginner in C so I apologize if this problem is too trivial,but yeah any help is appreciated

Comment: Scanf returns the number of elements read, not the value

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows that OP simply did not read the `scanf` documentation.

Comment: @0___________ There are more to that.

Comment: I suggest restructuring the code: first enter the values, than process them. This gives a more clean idea about what you want. Further: use indentation, it gives you the benefit of readable code.

Comment: You should indent your code. Unindented code is hard to read and to understand and therefore hard to maintain and to debug.

Comment: @Jabberwocky therefore error prone therefore more likely to be trashed sooner rather than later. :)

Comment: We get questions all the time that show that the OP hasn't reads docs or otherwise doesn't understand the tools they are trying to use.  That is not a valid reason for closure, and questions ordinarily are not closed for such a reason.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, learn that [`scanf()` does not return the matched value, it returns the number of items matched](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). You should

- Check the `scanf()` return value against the number of expected matches (`1` in this case)

  - If scanning is success, use the supplied argument to check the scanned value.
  - If scanning is failure, clean up the input buffer and ask for input again.

That said, in the code, when you start the loop from `i` value of `0`, you cannot use

```
array2[31-i]=array1[i];
```

as, for `i` value of 0, it will be like

```
array2[31]=array1[i];
```

which is [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error), you need to use

```
array2[31-i-1]=array1[i];
```

So that your array indexes are [0,31).

Comment: The OP's `array2[31 - i]` is worse than that: it's just plain wrong.  Whether a given input is even or odd, its correct index in `array2` is not a function of (only) the number of items read so far.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Very true, that's a logical failure assuming user is providing odd and even numbers sequentially.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah I just realized that I should remove the i from array2 and instead just assign 31 to a variable and decrease that variable when an array element is even.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks for the help,I will be making sure to read the documentation